# Looking for a shorter way to perform multiple random number assignments

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to complete a challenge where I have to generate two lists of random numbers, then pull the numbers the lists have in common into another list with no repeats. I've got something that works but I feel like it could be shorter. Is there a better way to assign a random range to the lists z and y? Is there a list comprehension that would work?

```
import random
from random import randrange 

z = list(range(random.randrange(1,100,1)))
y = list(range(random.randrange(1,100,1)))

for i in range(len(z)):
    z[i] = random.randint(1,1000)

for i in range(len(y)):
    y[i] = random.randint(1,1000)


c = { item for item in z if (item in y)}
print(c)
```

Comment: Use set intersection. It is much faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use random.sample for that and specify the numbers to be sampled by using a random integer:

```
y = random.sample(range(1, 1001), random.randint(1, 100))
z = random.sample(range(1, 1001), random.randint(1, 100))
set(y) & set(z)
Out[35]: {51, 585, 968}
```

As @Alan noted: For Python 2, it is better to use xrange instead of range as the range returns a list. For range(1000) this may not be a problem but for bigger ranges it may cause memory issues. You should also note that random.sample selects without replacement. If you want to select with replacement (so the numbers can be repeated) you can use a list comprehension as [@DeepSpace did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37242091/looking-for-a-shorter-way-to-perform-multiple-random-number-assignments/37242168#37242168) (Of course you don't want to convert it to a set so use [] instead of {} in that case).

Comment: Python 2 note (from the documentation): "To choose a sample from a range of integers, use an xrange() object as an argument."
General note (from the documentation): "Used for random sampling without replacement."  The original example sampled with replacement, whether intentionally or not.

Comment: @Alan You are correct on both accounts. I will add a note for xrange. For the replacement, I thought that wouldn't be important since the OP is using a set in the end but of course they might be interested in using those lists elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Python isn't Java or C. You don't need to first declare the list and then initialize each element as a new object.

Your whole code can be refactored into:

```
set_a = {random.randint(1,1000) for _ in range(random.randint(1,1000))}
set_b = {random.randint(1,1000) for _ in range(random.randint(1,1000))}

common_list = set_a & set_b
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this ?
[random.randint(1,1000) for i in range(100)]

Answer (score 0):

You could use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
import random
from random import randrange

z = [random.randint(1,1000) for x in range(100)]
y = [random.randint(1,1000) for x in range(100)]

c = set(y) & set(z)
print(c)
```

Comment: This got me there. Thanks.